# jQuery ajax call with API key

Tags: java, jquery, html, ajax, api

I have coded an AJAX call, but I don't know how to use the API key that the API has provided. Where do I put it in? Please provide with code example.

The API key should be sent in the header:

```
request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'key="mykey"');
```

```js
function myFunc() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://example.php",
    dataType: "JSON",
  }).done(function(data) {
    // Done
  }).fail(function(data) {
    // Failed
  });
}
```

Comment: It would depend on how the API is configured. Some need the key in the header, some in the request body. Can you give some more detail on how the API deals with authentication

Comment: It depends on which API are you using. Either you send it in the header or in request body. You might need to read the documentation of the API.

Comment: It says: request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'key="myKey"');

Answer (score 2):

To add a header to the AJAX request you can set the `headers` property. Try this:

```
function myFunc() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://example.php",
    dataType: "JSON",    
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'key=[YOUR_API_KEY_HERE...]'
    }
  }).done(function(data) {
    // Done
  }).fail(function(data) {
    // Failed
  });
}
```

Comment: Says bad request

Comment: Are you sure that's how the API expects to receive the key?

Comment: Ye the server says the API key is null, So I'm sending in a null key?

Comment: That would make sense. You need to check you're sending the right thing to the right place

Comment: As in if its post or get? Because these calls worked before the api key was implemented